# ANTLR4 match any not-matched sections into one single STRING token

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a Lexer/Parser with ANTLR that can parse plain text with 'tags' scattered inbetween. 
These tags are denoted by opening ({) and closing  (}) brackets and they represent Java objects that can evaluate to a string, that is then replaced in the original input to create a dynamic template of sorts.

Here is an example: 
{player:name} says hi! 
The {player:name} should be replaced by the name of the player and result in the output i.e. Mark says hi! for the player named Mark.

Now I can recognize and parse the tags just fine, what I have problems with is the text that comes after. 
This is the grammar I use:

```
    grammar : content+

    content : tag 
            | literal
            ;

    tag : player_tag
        | <...>
        | <other kinds of tags, not important for this example>
        | <...>
        ;

    player_tag : BRACKET_OPEN player_identifier SEMICOLON player_string_parameter BRACKET_CLOSE ;
    player_string_parameter : NAME
                            | <...>
                            ;
    player_identifier : PLAYER ;

    literal : NUMBER
            | STRING
            ;

    BRACKET_OPEN : '{';
    BRACKET_CLOSE : '}';

    PLAYER : 'player'
    NAME : 'name'

    NUMBER : <...>
    STRING : (.+)? /* <- THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART !*/
```

Now this STRING Lexer definition should match anything that is not an empty string but the problem is that it is too greedy and then also consumes the { } bracket tokens needed for the tag rule. 
I have tried setting it to ~[{}]+ which is supposed to match anything that does not include the { } brackets but that screws with the tag parsing which I don't understand either. 
I could set it to something like [ a-zA-Z0-9!"§$%&/()= etc...]+ but I really don't want to restrict it to parse only characters available on the british keyboard (German umlaute or French accents and all other special characters other languages have must to work!)
The only thing that somewhat works though I really dislike it is to force strings to have a prefix and a suffix like so:

```
  STRING : '\'' ~[}{]+ '\'' ;
```

This forces me to alter the form from "{player:name} says hi!" to "{player:name}' says hi!'" and I really desperately want to avoid such restrictions because I would then have to account for literal ' characters in the string itself and it's just ugly to work with.

The two solutions I have in mind are the following:
- Is there any way to match any number of characters that has not been matched by the lexer as a STRING token and pass it to the parser? That way I could match all the tags and say the rest of the input is just plain text, give it back to me as a STRING token or whatever...
- Does ANTLR support lookahead and lookbehind regex expressions with which I could match any number of characters before the first '{', after the last '}' and anything inbetween '}' and '{' ?
I have tried

```
  STRING : (?<=})(.+)?(?={) ;
```

but I can't seem to get the syntax right because that won't compile at all, which leads me to believe that ANTLR does not support lookahead and lookbehind syntax, but I could not find a definitive answer on the internet to that question.

Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antlr does not support lookahead or lookbehind. It does support non-greedy wildcard matches, but only when the `.*` non-greedy wildcard is followed *in the rule* with the termination sequence (which, as you say, is also contained in the match, although you could push it back into the input stream).

So `~[{}]*` is correct. But there's a little problem: lexer rules are (normally) always active. So that lexer rule will be active *inside the braces* as well, which means that it will swallow the entire contents between the braces (unless there are nested braces or braces inside quotes or some such, and that's even worse).

So you need to define different lexical contents, called "lexical modes" in Antlr. There's a [publically viewable example](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/islands.pdf) in the Antlr Definitive Reference, which shows a solution to a very similar problem: parsing HTML.

Comment: For this simple example, lexical modes work. However, as soon as I introduce nested tags that approach breaks down as well. The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference you referred to shows an example of mode usage when parsing xml, however one key difference to xml is the possibility of tags inside tags.

Comment: I believe though, that is a problem with my parser grammar, not the lexer. The lexer tokens now seem to be correctly identified, but the parser sees something like 
```
{<outer_tag>{<inner tag>}}
```
and parses the inner tag as {<inner tag>}} which leaves the outer tag without a closing bracket. 

Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: @neph: How do you end up with nested tags? Are the inner tags inside string literals or some such? Or are you talking about normal braces inside the Java code, which are not tags at all. Probably you need to correctly lex the Java, which requires identifying Java string literals (and comments). You should be able to find a lexical grammar for Java without too much work, and if not it wouldn't be too hard to write.

Comment: I fixed my issue and thought I would share it in case anybody else comes across it.

@nici the lexical modes did indeed work. I used "pushMode(...)" and "popMode" and this works like a charm. It didn't in the beginning because I forgot to pushMode from within the tag mode as well so the tag mode only got pushed once and no nested tags were possible.